# Sourcetree style changelist

Tags: plasticscm

I've used Plastic for a few years and have recently been "introduced" to Sourcetree. Most of Sourcetree I don't like, save for one thing. In the Plastic branch explorer, is there any way to display the changed files in a split screen under the changesets, similar to how SourceTree does it?

[SourceTree changes][1]
[Plastic Image][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UazuW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv53B.png

As far as I'm aware, the only way to bring this up in branch explorer is to do a code review. That's great, but a bit cumbersome if you are browsing through many changesets in a branch.

Any advice would be great!  Thanks